# Pythonic way to 'encourage' use of factory-method to instantiate class

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to prevent mistakes when instanciating a complex class with lots of rules to instanciate it correctly.

For example I came up with the following complex class:

```
import math

sentinel = object()

class Foo( object ):
    def __init__( self, a, c, d, g, b=sentinel, e=sentinel, f=sentinel, h=sentinel,
        i=sentinel ): 
    # sentinel parameters are only needed in case other parameters have some value, and in 
    # some cases should be None, __init__ contains only simple logic.
        ...

def create_foo( a, c, d, g ):
    # contains the difficult logic to create a Foo-instance correctly, e.g:
    b = ( int( math.pi * 10**a ) / float(10**a) )

    if c == "don't care":
       e = None
       f = None
    elif c == 'single':
       e = 3
       f = None
    else:
       e = 6
       f = 10

    if g == "need I say more":
        h = "ni"
        i = "and now for something completely different"
    elif g == "Brian":
        h = "Always look at the bright side of life"
        i = None
    else:
        h = None
        i = "Always look at the bright side of death"

    return Foo( a=a, b=b, c=c, d=d, e=e, f=f, g=g, h=h, i=i )
```

Since create_foo contains the logic to correctly create a Foo-instance I want to 'encourage'* users to use it. 
What is the best pythonic way to do this.

*Yes I know I can't *force* people to use the factory-function, hence I want to 'encourage' them. ;-)

Comment: You can't do that. If you believe this is the best way to generate `Foo` instance, use your code in the constructor and force to pass only `a, c, d, g`. If you don't, post it as a reference in the docs or leave it as a misc function in your module.

Comment: You can call `create_foo( a, c, d, g )` in your `__init__` allowing users to still use the constructor and `create_foo` method

Comment: @EmmanuelMtali then he would better do if he uses `create_foo` **as** `__init__`

Comment: You can prefix your class name with an underscore, in which case its name is invisible to code that imports the module.

Comment: @PaulCornelius but he want people to be able to use the class directly

Comment: @Uriel You can still USE the class, you just can't call its constructor.

Comment: @Uriel Separating a complex operation to its own function sounds great to me, but i thinks any of the way works well . .  its a matter of perspective!

Comment: @PaulCornelius OP specified he want's people to be able to call the constructor by themselves

Comment: Why can't you force them? Generate a sentinel object that is passed to the constructor by the factory function -> If it doesn't match, the factory function isn't calling it, so throw an `InstantiationRequiresFactoryException`.

Comment: @Uriel What he said was "Yes I know I can't force people to use the factory-function, hence I want to 'encourage' them."  But that's not entirely true; he *can* force them (provided they cannot modify the source code) by hiding the class name as I described.  It's as simple as typing one character and it accomplishes what he asked for.

Comment: @PaulCornelius he means he cant enforce them to use it *as long as it is not part of the foo constructor itself*; the user can activate it or not. if he were to enforce, he could just embed it into the constructor -look my prev comments

Comment: @PaulCornelius That doesn't hide the class name; it just prevents it from being imported by `from foo import *`. It can still be accessed by `foo._HiddenClass`.

Comment: @Uriel: shuffled order was a mistake. I just wanted to give an example of the idea and meant that the constructor was called using named arguments. <blush>

And I meant that I like the users *NOT* to use the constructor directly, but the factory-function. But this being python, you can't force them like chepner already points out. Only encourage them by making it 'hidden'.

Comment: The key to solving this is marking the origin of the object in the factory and in the constructor (`__new__`), and checking the origin in the initializer (`__init__`). Do a  `warnings.warn()` if it was the `__new__` method by itself. You mark the origin in the factory by calling `__new__` and `__init__` separately in the factory and marking the factory origin in between.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### TL/DR

The key to solving this is marking the origin of the object in the factory and in the constructor (`__new__`), and checking the origin in the initializer (`__init__`). Do a  `warnings.warn()` if the origin was the `__new__` method by itself. You mark the origin in the factory by calling `__new__` and `__init__` separately in the factory and marking the factory origin in between.

### Preamble

Since `create_foo` is the *preferred* method, it would likely be better to use that as the default. Implement the complex logic in the constructor, and refer to the lighter weight factory in your documentation as an alternative in those cases when the user doesn't want the complex logic. This avoids the problem of having to inform the user they are "doing it wrong".

However, assuming it is best to keep the complex logic out of the default constructor, your problem is twofold:

1. You need to implement - and detect - multiple methods of creation.

   This first part is simple; lots of objects in the standard library have alternate constructors, so this is not unusual at all in the Python world. You could use a factory method as you have created already, but at the end I suggest reasons for including the factory in your class (this is what `@classmethod` was created for).

   Detecting the origin is a little harder, but not too difficult. You simply mark the origin at instantiation and check the origin at initialization. Do this by calling `__new__` and `__init__` separately.
2. You want to inform the user what they *should* be doing, but still allow them to do what they want to do.

   This is exactly what the `warnings` module was created for.

---

### Use `warnings`

You can issue messages to the user- and still allow them to be in control of the messages- using the [`warnings` module](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/warnings.html). Notify the user that they might want to use the factory by doing:

```
import warnings
warnings.warn("It is suggested to use the Foo factory.", UserWarning)
```

This way, the user can [filter the warnings out if they wish](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/warnings.html#the-warnings-filter).

---

### A `warnings` warning

Quick sidebar: note that once the above `warnings.warn` message has been executed, then by default it will not come up again until you execute `warnings.resetwarnings()` or the Python session is restarted.

In other words, unless you change the settings the user will only see the message the first time they make a `Foo`. This may or may not be what you want.

---

### Add origin attributes and check origin at initialization

Utilizing `warnings.warn` requires tracking the method of origin for your `foo`s, and calling the warning if the factory isn't used. You could do it relatively simply as follows.

First, add a `__new__` method and do an origin check at the end of the `__init__` method:

```
class Foo( object ):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs): 
        inst = super(Foo, cls).__new__(cls)
        # mark the instance origin:
        inst.origin == cls.__new__
        return inst
    def __init__( self, a, c, d, g, b=sentinel, e=sentinel, f=sentinel, 
                    h=sentinel, i=sentinel ):
        #### simple logic ####
        if self.origin == type(self).__new__:
            warnings.warn("It is suggested to use the {} factory for \
                              instance creation.".format(type(self).__name__), UserWarning)
```

Then in the factory, *instantiate* and *initialize* the new object **separately**, and setting the origin between the two:

```
def create_foo( a, c, d, g ):
    #### complex logic #####
    # instantiate using the constructor directly:
    f = Foo.__new__(Foo, a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i )
    # replace the origin with create_foo:
    f.origin = create_foo
    # NOW initialize manually:
    f.__init__(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i )
    return f
```

Now you can detect where any `Foo` is coming from, and a warning will be issued to the user (once by default) if they did not use the factory function:

```
>>> Foo()
>>> __main__:8: UserWarning: It is suggested to use the Foo factory for instance creation.
```

---

### Allow for `Foo` subclassing

One other suggested tweak: I would consider adding your factory function into the class as an alternate constructor, and then (in your user warning) suggesting the user use that constructor (rather than the factory function itself) for instantiation. This would allow `Foo`'s child classes to utilize the factory method and still receive an instance of the child class from the factory, rather than a `Foo`.

Allowing for classes other than `Foo` to utilize the factory requires some minor changes to the factory:

```
def create_foo( foo_cls, a, c, d, g ):
    '''Contains Foo creation logic.'''
    #### complex logic #####
    f = foo_cls.__new__(foo_cls, a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i )
    # replace the marked origin with create_foo
    f.origin = create_foo
    # now initialize
    f.__init__(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i )
    return f
```

Now we'll add the alternate constructor:

```
class Foo( object ):
    #### other methods ####
    def create(cls, *args, **kwargs): 
        inst = create_foo(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        return inst
```

Now we can:

```
f = Foo.create( a, c, d, g )
```

But we can also:

```
class Bar(Foo):
    pass

b = Bar.create( a, c, d, g )
```

And we still see this:

```
>>> Bar()
>>> __main__:8: UserWarning: It is suggested to use the Bar factory for instance creation.
```

Comment: Very nice and clear explanation of a nice concept. Thanx. Since I asked for "the best pythonic way" I leave the question open for a few days to check if other people come with other solutions / discuss about the given solutions, but I like this.

Comment: @Nemelis I don't know if it's the best, but `warnings` is in the standard library and a lot better than just doing `print` statements, and I'm not aware of another way of notifying the user of an issue at runtime without raising an exception (and ending the program as a result).

Answer (score 1):

You can strongly restrict the ordering of operations/properties.

Meaning preventing user from accessing some of class `Foo` method before calling `create_foo` method! The same idea is used in [Serializer Module](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/serializers.py#L92)

Sample code:-

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b = sentinel):
        self.a = a
        self._create_foo_called = False

    def create_foo(self):
        self.b = "complex value"
        self._create_foo_called = True

    def do_something(self):
       if(self._create_foo_called):
           # WHATEVER
       else:
           raise AssertionError("Please call create_foo() method")
```